# Remove text before first comma

Tags: javascript, string

I have the following text:

```
Kenya, Garden, PFO, Inv 2123, DG, Lot 5543, Ra
```

And I only want to show the text after the first `,`

Result:

```
Garden, PFO, Inv 2123, DG, Lot 5543, Ra
```

How can I do this with Javascript?

Comment: In order to get good quality answers, please edit your question to include what you have tried so far. That way we can know at which point you've been stuck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
var text = "Kenya, Garden, PFO, Inv 2123, DG, Lot 5543, Ra";
console.log(text.replace(/^[^,]+, */, ''));
```

Answer (score 10):

Split string by `,` delimiter and remove first item of array using [`Array.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) and then join array.

```js
var str = "Kenya, Garden, PFO, Inv 2123, DG, Lot 5543, Ra";
var newStr = str.split(", ").slice(1).join(", ");
console.log(newStr);
```

Also you can find index of first `,` and get all string after it using [`String.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice).

```js
var str = "Kenya, Garden, PFO, Inv 2123, DG, Lot 5543, Ra";
var newStr = str.slice(str.indexOf(',')+1).trim();
console.log(newStr);
```

Answer (score 4):

In the simplest way:

```
let input = "Kenya, Garden, PFO, Inv 2123, DG, Lot 5543, Ra";
let index = input.indexOf(','); // find the index of first ,
let result = index>-1? input.substring(index+1): input;
```

You can also add `trim()`, to remove unwanted white spaces.

Comment: Or just `result = input.substring(input.indexOf(',')+1)`

Comment: True, but you would have to be certain, that there is a , character in the input.

Comment: If `,` is missing, you'll get equivalent of `input.substring(0)`

Answer (score 2):

**You can try this mate**

```js
let str = "Kenya, Garden, PFO, Inv 2123, DG, Lot 5543, Ra";

let op = str.replace(/^\w+,/, '');
console.log(op)
```

**Note:-** `str.replace(/^\w+,/, '').trim()` in case you want to remove leading and trialling spaces.

**P.S** - All the other answers are also right. I just wanted to share one more way of doing it. :)

Answer (score 1):

@Mohammed answer is a good way. An other one is to get first coma and remove text before.

```
var str = "Kenya, Garden, PFO, Inv 2123, DG, Lot 5543, Ra";
var newStr = str.substring(str.indexOf(',') + 1).trim();
console.log(newStr);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like that :

```js
var text = "Kenya, Garden, PFO, Inv 2123, DG, Lot 5543, Ra";
console.log(text.substring(text.indexOf(',')+1).trim());
```

Note that **trim()** function removes whitespace from both sides of the string.

Answer (score 1):

Solution with regular expression :

```js
let input = "Kenya, Garden, PFO, Inv 2123, DG, Lot 5543, Ra";

let res = /,(.*\w+)/.exec(input)[1];
console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
    var str = "Kenya, Garden, PFO, Inv 2123, DG, Lot 5543, Ra";
    var arr = str.split(',');
    arr.splice(0, 1);
    console.log(arr.join(','));
```

The procedure is simple. Just first split the string with comma(,) and it returns an array. Then splice the first index of the array by `arr.splice(0,1)`, Here 0 is the index number and 1 for how many elements you want to remove. Finally join the array with comma(,).